# Pandas Сохранение в CSV, Excel Ошибка

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Здравствуйте пытаюсь сохранить результат парсинга в CSV файл с помощью Pandas, но выкидывает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/sdvk-oboi.ru/sdvk-oboi.ru.py", line 183, in crawl
    urls = await future
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "D:/Git/sdvk-oboi.ru/sdvk-oboi.ru.py", line 173, in parse
    pd.DataFrame(all).to_csv(r'products.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 348, in __init__
    mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 459, in _init_dict
    return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7356, in _arrays_to_mgr
    index = extract_index(arrays)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7402, in extract_index
    raise ValueError('arrays must all be same length')
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

Скорее всего это происходит из-за попытки сохранить этот текст в одно из полей (условие заказчика: весь  с тегами)

```
<ul class="list-options">
                    <li itemprop="ProductModel" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ProductModel">
                        <table class="attr-line-table"><tr>
<td class="first"><label>Артикул:</label></td>
                        <td><span itemprop="name">5438</span></td>
                        </tr></table>
                    </li>
                    <li itemprop="brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand">
                        <table class="attr-line-table"><tr>
<td class="first"><label>Производитель:</label></td>
                        <td><a itemprop="name" href="/oboi/Zambaiti_Parati/">Zambaiti Parati</a></td>
                        </tr></table>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <table class="attr-line-table"><tr>
<td class="first"><label>Страна:</label></td>
                        <td><a itemprop="name" href="/oboi/italiya/">Италия</a></td>
                        </tr></table>
                    </li>


                                        <li itemprop="additionalProperty" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
                        <table class="attr-line-table"><tr>
<td class="first"><label itemprop="name">Ширина рулона:</label></td>
                        <td><span itemprop="value" id="a1val">106 см</span></td>
                        </tr></table>
                    </li>
                        <li itemprop="additionalProperty" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
                        <table class="attr-line-table"><tr>
<td class="first"><label itemprop="name">Длина рулона:</label></td>
                        <td><span itemprop="value" id="a2val">10.05 м</span></td>
                        </tr></table>
                    </li>
                        <li itemprop="additionalProperty" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
                        <table class="attr-line-table"><tr>
<td class="first"><label itemprop="name">Основа:</label></td>
                        <td><span itemprop="value" id="a3val">Флизелин</span></td>
                        </tr></table>
                    </li>
                        <li itemprop="additionalProperty" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
                        <table class="attr-line-table"><tr>
<td class="first"><label itemprop="name">Материал:</label></td>
                        <td><span itemprop="value" id="a4val">Винил</span></td>
                        </tr></table>
                    </li>


<!-- a65 wuz here -->
    </ul>
```

Как можно исправить?
Код:

```
temp = []
        try:
            name = html.cssselect("h1[itemprop='name']")[0].text
        except:
            name = None
        temp.append(["Название", name])
        # print(name)
        try:
            price = html.cssselect('#item-price')[0].text
        except:
            price = None
        temp.append(["Цена", price])

        # print(price)

        ul = html.cssselect('ul.list-options')[0]
        print_html(ul)
        temp.append(["Характеристики", ul])

        try:
            url_main_photo = "http:"+html.cssselect("div.main-photo ")[0].get("data-fancybox-href")
        except:
            url_main_photo = None
        # print(url_main_photo)
        temp.append(["Основная картинка", url_main_photo])
        download_image(url_main_photo)

        urls_image_list = []
        block_images = html.cssselect('#collection_photo>div>a')
        for block in block_images:
            urls_image_list.append("http:" + block.get("href"))

        # print(urls_image_list)

        temp.append(["Изображения", urls_image_list])

        all = (dict(temp))
        pd.DataFrame(all).to_csv(r'products.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка оказалась в том, что я пытался сохранить элемент ul как часть, которая создается при
`lxml.html.fromstring(request)` у библиотеки lxml

Заменив на `lxml.html.tostring(html, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True)`, я смог устранить эту ошибку